# Linux : How to delete locked file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to remove `xyz_DB.lock.db file`. I tried as root but couldn't delete it. How to remove it in terminal. My initial requirement was remove a folder. but it includes this locked file. And is there anyway to delete folder directly which include a locked file ?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Check with `lsattr` command if the immutable bit is set for the file, it will show (i)

```
# lsattr file
----i--------e- file
```

If so, change it using following command:

```
# chattr -i file
```

And then try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try either changing the files permissions through the GUI or use rm -rf on the directory that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

try "chown" to  provide permission to your file/folder and then delete it,

e.g: assume username= amol and filename=myfile.txt,,

For File:---  sudo chown amol:amol myfile.txt

For Folder:-- sudo chown -R amol:amol directory_name